# Default rotation value make shape jumps to origin

Tags: reactjs, canvas, konvajs

I use KonvaJS to draw my points in Canvas. After that, I set for it an default rotation value (45deg). I think it should be rotate at center point of it. But This shape jumps to origin.

```
const [points, setPoints] = useState([
    [50, 100],
    [150, 100],
    [150, 200],
    [50, 200]
  ]);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      
        <Line
          ref={shapRef}
          points={flatPoints(points)}
          stroke={"#E90000"}
          strokeWidth={1}
          closed
          strokeScaleEnabled={false}
          draggable={true}
          onDragEnd={handleDragEnd}
          onTransformEnd={handleTransformEnd}
          rotation={45}
        />
   </Fragment>
```

Images to describe my problem:

[shape without rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjw40.png)

[shape with rotation 45deg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zS9l1.png)

How to make shape always rotate at center point of it ?

Answer (score 0):

Every `Konva.Shape` rotates around its origin. By default, the origin of the shape is its `{x, y}` point, which is `{0, 0}` by default. You need to move the origin of the shape to the center of your visible rectangle.

You can do it using `offset` property or by just drawing rectangle around of shape origin. In both cases, you will need to set `x` and `y` differently. `x` and `y` will "set the position of the center of the rectangle on the canvas".

```js
<Line
  x={100}
  y={150}
  points={[
    [50, 100],
    [150, 100],
    [150, 200],
    [50, 200]
  ].flat()}
  offsetX={100}
  offsetY={150}
  stroke={"#E90000"}
  strokeWidth={1}
  closed
  strokeScaleEnabled={false}
  draggable={true}
  rotation={45}
/>

<Line
  x={250}
  y={150}
  points={[
    [-50, -50],
    [50, -50],
    [50, 50],
    [-50, 50]
  ].flat()}
  stroke={"#E90000"}
  strokeWidth={1}
  closed
  strokeScaleEnabled={false}
  draggable={true}
  rotation={45}
/>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-konva-line-rotation-demo-y6w948?file=/src/index.js